# PGSQL - How do I Add 5 hours to DATE in WHERE Clause?

Tags: postgresql

I either need to add 5 hours or convert from GMT to EST. The return is currently showing everything from 7p and later yesterday...

```
WHERE
incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
DATE(incident.install_completed) = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: See [the list of date time functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) and [the `AT TIME ZONE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

Comment: better compare against now() at time zone 'WANTED TZ' - manually ajusting time zones is mostly painfull

Comment: You could use `DATE(col) + INTERVAL '5 HOUR'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually adding interval to get wanted time zone, use at time zone, eg:

```
t=# select now(), now() at time zone 'est';
             now              |         timezone
------------------------------+---------------------------
 2017-04-07 07:07:39.17234+00 | 2017-04-07 02:07:39.17234
(1 row)
```

Depending on your timezone, exactly same statement adding interval to your date gives different result, eg at DST shift hour:

```
t=# set timezone TO 'WET';
SET
t=# select '2017-03-26 00:00:00'::timestamptz + '1 hour'::interval;
        ?column?
------------------------
 2017-03-26 02:00:00+01
(1 row)

t=# set timezone TO 'EET';
SET
t=# select '2017-03-26 00:00:00'::timestamptz + '1 hour'::interval;
        ?column?
------------------------
 2017-03-26 01:00:00+02
(1 row)
```